# Is there any hotkey to jump between braces?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, is there any hotkey to jump between braces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> if you need to find the matching bracket of the selected one.

Also note that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to see all available key shortcuts for the editor you're in (and use it a second time to see a list of all potential key bindings, along with the ability to filter on the list and edit the shortcuts).

Comment: @Joachim I didn't know about the "keyboard" tags, thanks for editing ... and letting me know of it :p.

Answer (score 2):

The following shortcut will jump to the matching brace or print "No matching bracket found" if it doesn't exist.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Can also be used for parentheses, brackets and diamonds.